# force.com setup on eclipse in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apex, community

I am not able to set up force.com project on eclipse.
when i am adding repository there is a error comes : **"could not find http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42"**

and i am having java 1.8
eclipse 3.8
and OS ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

**Configure Eclipse to use your proxy server. These settings can be found in your Eclipse Preferences, under General > Network Connections.**

You can use reference from the link below

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation